# Spring batch job throws error like 'Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step'

Tags: spring-batch

We have spring batch job which is processing 100 million records in multithreded job with scaling process like partitioning. Here master step create 500 paritions and those are being processed by 100 threads. But sometimes job is failing with just following exception. If I rerun the job without any code change it just works. Can someone explain what might be causing issue in slave step which is running in diff thread which makes master step to fail and stop processing further.

```
2015-09-11 17:22:21,365 ERROR [task-scheduler-9] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step productImport.master in job productImportJob
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler.launch(JobLaunchingMessageHandler.java:50) [spring-batch-integration-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway.handleRequestMessage(JobLaunchingGateway.java:76) [spring-batch-integration-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:74) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:219) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: You're missing the cause of the exception.  Why did the slave step fail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560233/spring-batch-partitioned-step-stopped-after-hours-from-when-a-non-skippable-exce/23566889#23566889?newreg=2eb5cbabf7a3485283c92d1d92948f72
here is the answer of this question

Answer (score 2):

First adjust "maxPoolSize" property, if still facing the issue, adjust these other properties of your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (assuming you using the same) according to the load on your job.

```
<property name="corePoolSize" value="20">
<property name="queueCapacity" value="20">
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="20">
<property name="allowCoreThreadTimeout" value="true">
```

Comment: It is certanly correct. "[ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step in job" This error is related to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. If it has not enough thread pool size then it interrupts to processing and it throws the error.

Comment: thanks a bunch for your answer, finally I got hang of davestated problem

Comment: Can any one post the solution for this question